# Amplify: how to require/import custom function from lambda layer?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have an Amplify project where I would like to use lambda layers. The layer and lambda have been configured using Amplify CLI.

Lambda layer in named as 'common'. The file is `./amplify/backend/function/common/opt/param.js`. It exports one function:

```
const getValue = async (name) => {
...
}
module.exports = getValue;
```

In my lambda function I would like to use the above helper function. However, I do not know how to import this. I have tried:

```
const getValue = require('param');
const getValue = require('./param');
const getValue = require('/opt/param');
const getValue = require('./opt/param');
```

but they all fail with error like:

```
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module '/opt/param'
```

Note also that I have updated the lambda after pushing the layer and its connected to the latest layer version. So the code should be available for the lambda.

Answer (score 3):

You can put this in your `package.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "layer": "file:../../opt/"
    }
}
```

And then you install the packages.

```
const { ... } = require('layer/...');
```

Comment: This is the most solid and less "magical" way to include layers.

After you do this, you will need to run `amplify function build -y` to populate the assets in the all the functions that are using the layer.

This also addresses the comment that @user20358 brought up about using multiple layers in one function. To accomplish this, all you'd need to do to is add another entry for your other layer e.g. `"layer2": "file:../../Layer2Folder/"`

Comment: I did find an interesting "issue", this doesn't at least for me, keep up with new changes to your layers. After you run `amplify function build -y` once, then update your layer in it's own folder, you need to manually delete the generated assets and then run a rebuild. This can be automated via, npm script, but is annoying.

Answer (score 3):

*(Adding an answer too so that this important info is not hidden in comment section).*

This was a bug in Amplify CLI.  It has been fixed in version 4.25.0.

The correct way to import layer code (located in `opt/` directory) is now again logical:

`require('/opt/<module-name>')`

Comment: Is there a python version of this?

Comment: If there are multiple layers each having an opt folder, how do you distinguish between them? What if you want to include a file with the same name in both the opt folders?

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for a better explanation/solution (or if it might be a bug?) but if you put modules in the default opt/ directory generated by amplify it shows up here:
`const getValue = require('/opt/opt/param');`

Comment: Excellent! My lambda layer code is indeed in the `opt/` directory and I can confirm that the path of this answer works. Feels odd to use `/opt/opt/` so could be bug too as support for lambda layers in new in Amplify.

Comment: Submitted this as bug report (https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/6297) to see if this intended. At least documentation should be improved to clarify the use.

Comment: The bug has been fixed now on amplify-cli 4.25.0. So from that version on the correct way is again logical: `require('/opt/param');`

Comment: Is there a python equivalent way to do this? Using the statement `from opt.<module-name> import myClass` gives a module not found error